spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings What's its actual purpose or use?
What is the real use of spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings property if i am using streambridge instead of supplier for producer ? what if i skip this property  ? Is it mandatory with use of Streambridge ?
from here, though its mentions that binding will be pre-created but its not giving complete clarity. Is this property man
My yml looks something like this below -:
Spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: consumerinput
  stream:
    output-bindings: hardstopproducer
    bindings:
      consumerinput-in-0:
        group: team.queue.cit.user
        contentType: application/json
        binder: rabbit
      consumerretry:
        group: team.queue.cit.user
        destination: team.river.retry
        contentType: application/json
        binder: rabbit
      hardstopproducer:
        destination: team.river
        contentType: application/json
        binder: rabbit

I am getting below issue if i use output-binding-:
message":"Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - configure access to exchange 'hardstopproducer' in vhost 'dev' refused for clinical 'hardstopproducer'
In rabbitMQ user , access has been provides such that only this exchanges starting with "team" keyword will be allowed to created.
My expectation is spring cloud stream should not try to create an exchange with the name i have provided in the producer binding since the name provided under output-bindings and the binding name  are same. So no autoProvisioning should be done here.

The documentation for spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings reads as follows:
A semi-colon delimited string to explicitly define output bindings (specifically for cases when there is no implicit trigger to create such bindings such as Function, Supplier or Consumer).
Since you don't have a function binding it would imply you need to list the output-bindings you plan to use.
Extra:
It seems that if you have named bindings and destinations then using StreamBridge.send results in messages going where you expect.

Agreed, i have gone through this which stated that for pre-create the producer bindings , we need this property .  But there is an issue when only one consumer is s present in the service.It will force all those exposed under output-binding to go for autprovisioning.
Please take a look on below
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/3034 and the last 2  comments of https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2170    . So i wanted to know what will happen if i dont use this property .

Have look at this project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/main/restaurant-stream-apps-3 there are no output-bindings. Just a collection of named bindings and destinations and using StreamBridge to send message to the bindings

thankx for the reposne , i l take a look . So If i frame my doubt in simple words -:  Do i really need output-bindings property  if i am using Streambridge  ?

You don't need output-bindings if you use StreamBridge.
